# Possibility of a number to have a remainder of 3 when divided by 2

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it possible for a number divided by 2 to have a remainder of 3? If possible, can anyone explain it how it can be solve. If not, then why ?

Answer (score 2):

No, it can't. By the definition of the remainder (at least in an [Euclidian Division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division)), it has to be strictly lower than the divisor. So you can't have a remainder of 3 in a division by 2. You remainder have to be 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea of Euclidean division of a natural number $A$ by a natural number $n$ is that you remove $n$ from $A$ (which is possible if and only if $A\ge n$) as many times as possible, i.e. as long as what remains is  $\ge n$. You stop when it is no more possible; so the process stops when what remains is $< n$ (and still a natural number). So it is by definition that the remainder $r$ satisfies
$$0\le r<n.$$

Answer (score 0):

The remainder is always smaller than the divisor. This is a required condition for the quotient and remainder to be uniquely defined.

Imagine

$$15 = 2\cdot 6+3$$ versus

$$15=2\cdot7+\color{green}1.$$

These are two valid identities, but we prefer the one with the smallest remainder, which gives the "best" quotient.

---

Said differently, the remainder $3$ is not possible because we can still divide it and get a nonzero quotient:

$$3=2\cdot1+\color{green}1.$$